# Mysql get records by week

Tags: mysql, database

i am having user table which having fields like this

```
id
username
email
created_at(unix timestamp)
```

now i want current year records by month with group of weekly data.
something like this

```
month/week      count(*)
jan(1)          55
jan(2)          102
jan(3)          23
jan(4)          39
feb(1)          6
feb(2)          14
feb(3)          37
feb(4)          20
.               .
.               .
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

Answer (score 1):

Check **[DATE / TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)** functions

```
 SELECT MONTH(created_at), WEEK(created_at), count(*)
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW())
 GROUP BY MONTH(created_at), WEEK(created_at)
```

Comment: The syntax is slightly wrong, `where` should come before the group by. I'm sure that it was just a typo.

Comment: @JorgeCampos You are right, I add the `WHERE` condition after give a second read to the question.